# .NET: Different target frameworks via project configuration

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, configuration

I would like to have two different .net framework targets via configuration in Visual Studio 2015. While for references, you can edit the CSPROJ file and add a conditions, this does not seem to work for the `TargetFrameworkVersion` in the first `PropertyGroup` of the file. I have the impression that any `Condition` in that element causes VS to completely ignore this element and to fall back to the default value of "v4.0".

Is there any way I can get different target framework versions for different configurations?

This is what I tried in the CSPROJ file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <!-- this is what VS2015 would put into the file:
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    -->
    <!-- this is what does not work: -->
    <TargetFrameworkVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'OLD_Debug' OR '$(Configuration)' == 'OLD_Release'">v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'NEW_Debug' OR '$(Configuration)' == 'NEW_Release'">v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

A similar approach with conditions for the assembly references works fine.

**EDIT**
I found a similar Stackoverflow question:
[Targetting multiple .net framework versions by using different project configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006397/targetting-multiple-net-framework-versions-by-using-different-project-configura) and tried the approach suggested in the non-accepted answer to remove the `TargetFrameworkVersion` from the first  `PropertyGroup` block, and edit the later `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'OLD_Debug|AnyCPU' ">` blocks to contain it, but my assembly is still compiled for framework 3.5 no matter which configuration I use. At least if I look at the assembly from Powershell using `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\PATH\MyAssembly.dll").ImageRuntimeVersion`, I always get version 2, not 4.

Comment: I did this before by having a build script pass the `TargetFrameworkVersion` as a parameter to MSBuild for each. Do note this can be accomplished far easier in Visual Studio 2017 with the [new `.csproj`](http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) format: `<TargetFrameworks>net35;net45;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>`, which builds all versions in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23705790/7897151) to a similar question works:
Keep the first `PropertyGroup` without configuration specific settings, remove the `TargetFrameworkVersion` element from it. And add the `TargetFrameworkVersion` settings to the configuration specific `PropertyGroup`s which are in the file anyway, just double them for debug/release:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'OLD_Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'OLD_Release|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'NEW_Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'NEW_Release|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

I verified this as follows:

1. My assembly references version 2.0.0.0 of the mscorlib assembly for the 3.5 framework (`OLD_...` configurations), and version 4.0.0.0 of mscorlib for the 4.0 framework (`NEW_...` configurations).
2. Using [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy#ilspy-------), I found that the 3.5 version of my assembly has no attribute for the target framework, as this was only introduced since version 4, but the version 4 framework appears as an attribute of the assembly:

   ```
   [assembly: TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.0", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4")]
   ```